# How to change the camera rotation in Threejs

Tags: css, 3d, three.js, user-input

I have make a 3D cone with CSS3Renderer and TrackballControl and it works properly.
http://chito.hk/three-test/

But now, I want to modify it to allow user input the values to control the camera rotation rather than using TrackballControl.
http://chito.hk/three-test/index_static.php

But the camera gives no response to the lookAt function. Can anyone tell me which part I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add a render(); call after your lookAt.

Comment: hi mdan... the camera is moving now, but it isn't moving as I have expected. I want the camera moves like using TrackballControl, turning spherically around the object.